# ScriptManager is not declared - err msg

Tags: vb.net, scriptmanager

I've this class and it gave me an error name 'ScriptManager is not declared'

```
Public NotInheritable Class ResponseHelper
Private Sub New()
End Sub
Public Shared Sub Redirect(ByVal response As HttpResponse, ByVal url As String, ByVal target As String, ByVal windowFeatures As String)
    If ([String].IsNullOrEmpty(target) OrElse target.Equals("_self", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) AndAlso [String].IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures) Then
        response.Redirect(url)
    Else
        Dim page As Page = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
        If page Is Nothing Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot redirect to new window outside Page context.")
        End If
        url = page.ResolveClientUrl(url)
        Dim script As String
        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(windowFeatures) Then
            script = "window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"", ""{2}"");"
        Else
            script = "window.open(""{0}"", ""{1}"");"
        End If
        script = [String].Format(script, url, target, windowFeatures)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, GetType(Page), "Redirect", script, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

This code from this link:
http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2007/09/25/response-redirect-into-a-new-window-with-extension-methods.aspx

I've been 8 hours trying to figure out how to open a new page and send parameters to it. And found this code , and 6 hours trying to apply it but nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Ajax to be installed to access the Scriptmanager.
Use [Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) instead. 
If you want a solution that works whether AJAX is available or not, have a look [at this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2006/11/13/HOWTO_3A00_-Write-controls-compatible-with-UpdatePanel-without-linking-to-the-ASP.NET-AJAX-DLL.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try put the full name space before scirptmananger, System.UI.Web.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(...)